# Is this the proper way to fix a front reflector in a bmw x3?

Tags: bmw, repair

So I drive a 2008 BMW X3 and maybe one year ago the front reflector came off after I bumped the front bumper. No other damage was caused & I picked up the reflector and got it fixed by a bmw dealership shortly thereafter. They used the same piece (at least that's what they told me) and *supposedly* fixed it by replacing the clips on the inner part of the bumper.

Fast forward to a few days ago & **without hitting anything** the reflector popped out. I saw I was missing it when I looked at the front of my car & I found it laying inside of the front bumper. I picked it out and saw what looked like a whole lot of glue around the edges of it. The clips for it were in-tact and nothing appeared to broken about it.

My question is, did BMW basically scam me into paying for a fixed reflector and instead just glued it on? Is this the proper or acceptable way to fix this issue?

[image: Where Reflector should be]

[image: What I assume is glue]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mechanics.SE. I don't know if you got scammed, but will tell you, this is body work which was done and paid for ... most body shops I know (whether dealer owned or otherwise) warranties their work. Take it back and tell them their "fix" failed and to make it right.

Comment: thank you and thanks for the heads up, and perhaps scammed isn't the right word but I still feel ripped off for getting the work done by the dealership. I had planned on telling them to fix their mistake too.

Comment: I can tell you I had work done and they glued a piece of fender trim on because it had broken clips.  It fell off a year later in traffic.  I took it back and the manager looked disappointed by what the tech had done and was happy to order a new piece and install it at no cost to me.  That said, your piece almost looks like it was made to be glued on with those texured tabs.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm not sure of, if it's actually meant to be glued on then that's kinda silly considering the clips behind it but I do agree that it looks like it was meant to have glue on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like these reflectors are held on by cement and not clips. I had the same problem. It fell inside the bumper. I took it out and found it was fastened with some grey cement from factory. I peeled most of it off.

Guess you need to source some proper cement to get it back on. There are no clips

[image]